# How to save and load checked checkbox like a save file - php

Tags: php, database, checkbox, load, save

I am developing a webtool with the purpose of doing a conversion of a XML(xmi) file to a SQL file, following specific rules (determined by the user) through checkboxes.

So basically the user should be able to save the checkbox used in a kind of savefile for the next time he visits the website/webtool he can load and thus get the selected checkboxes in the last previous use, understand?

Therefore, the user indicates a name for the save file to be able to load the save file in a posterior visit. 
I dont know if this can be used :x    NEDD HELP :XXX

```
input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" id="chk[]" value="chk"> when a class doesn't have an Identifier a primary key will be automatically created in the corresponding table.
```

Comment: You could load the settings file and when you render the page with the options, add `checked="checked"` to the selected boxes.

Comment: I feel your pain. I have the exact same question/problem and I've been searching for a solution for several days now. It seems like either no one understands what is being asked or there just plain isn't a solution which I find very hard to believe. For my use, I have a very large form (over 2000 lines of code in the form part alone) and I need to be able to save a work in progress from time to time to reload later. I can't find a way to do it. All I need is an example to save 1 value to a file and reload it from that file and I can do the rest from there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understant you correctly, you want to save a user's settings, so that they are preserved for the next tieme the user comes to the site.

I would use [sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) to store the users' settings, then use code like this to have the checkboxes reflect the users' settings:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" id="chk[]" value="chk" <?php if ($_SESSION['someval']) { print 'checked="checked" '; } ?>>
```

Comment: By using sessions , will the user be able to save multiple savefiles? Because the site will have multiple checkboxes, each representing different parameters, so the user needs to have the possiblity to save those settings in separate files.

Comment: @user1384873: They wouldn't really be in "files," but yes, you can save many values that way.

Comment: And how can he load those settings ? Because what I really intend is for the user to be able to choose and load a certain previously saved "profile"(set of several checkbox values).

Comment: Oh, if you want the user to have several choices, I would store their settings-choices in a database, then use sessions to manage user logins, so you know whose choices are whose. As far as loading the settings, as soon as you retrieve the information from the database or $_SESSIONS var, then the data is loaded. You can use my code above to show that they're loaded.